# Temp Table Space "no rows selected"

Tags: oracle

I am trying list files in temp table space. but It says "no rows selected" Please explain why I am not getting the file added to the table space.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TESTRM;
Tablespace created.

ALTER  TABLESPACE TESTRM ADD TEMPFILE '+TESTDATA/rm/datafile/TESTRM_temp01.dbf' SIZE 2M;
Tablespace altered.

SQL> SELECT FILE_NAME, BYTES FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TESTRM';
no rows selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a tempfile to a temporary tablespace, so it won't show up in `dba_data_files`. Instead, you should query its information from [`dba_temp_files`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5061.htm):

```
SELECT FILE_NAME, BYTES FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TESTRM';
```

Answer (score 0):

Temp files are not data files. You need to query `dba_temp_files` instead to list them.

```
select file_name, bytes from dba_temp_files where tablespace_name = 'TESTRM';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks It worked.

```
SQL> SELECT FILE_NAME, BYTES FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TESTRM';

FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     BYTES
----------
/tmp/TESTRM/create/TESTRM/datafile/o1_mf_testrm_bvrywjkn_.tmp
 104857600

+TESTDATA/rm/datafile/testrm_temp01.dbf
   2097152
```